# Add Wiktionary as optional dictionary in Preview similar to how Moon+ Reader for Android has

Tags: preview, dictionary

I have found a few similar questions, but mostly revolving around wiktionary as part of the Dictionary app, which is not what I would like to do (besides the fact that this seems impossible, with the newer versions of macOS).

Instead, I would like to see if there is a way to add sources (like Wiktionary) to the pulldown menu of Preview, similar to how the Android Moon+ Reader Pro has, where you default to a specific dictionary for the pulldown menu **Dict**, but you also have a "More" option, where you could list all possible dictionaries, on- or off-line.